# HTML: draw cubic Bézier curve in multiple colors

Tags: html, svg, canvas, bezier

I am working with Bézier curves in HTML.

I have a cubic Bézier curve that I want to draw in multiple colors (color 1 from t = 0 to t = x, color 2 from t = x to t = 1). I could do this either with canvas or with SVG.

Is there a way to specify the stroke color based on the t value?

If not, is there a way to specify the t-interval in which the curve should be drawn? Then I could just draw it multiple times in different intervals with the particular color.

Comment: Like https://medium.com/@cereallarceny/getting-gradients-to-follow-along-svg-paths-in-javascript-45357b60bed7 you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your `<path>` into 2 separate paths at the given `t` value.

```js
let t = 0.75;
let path = document.querySelector('#pathCubic');

/**
 * parse pathData
 * quadratic and arc commands will be converted to cubic
 */
let pathData = path.getPathData({
  normalize: true
});
let pathDataSplit = splitNthPathSegmentAtT(pathData, 1, t);

let d0 = pathDataSplit[0].map(com => {
  return `${com.type} ${com.values.join(' ')}`
}).join(' ');
let d1 = pathDataSplit[1].map(com => {
  return `${com.type} ${com.values.join(' ')}`
}).join(' ');

// apply path data
pathSplit0.setAttribute('d', d0);
pathSplit1.setAttribute('d', d1);


/**
 * split nth path segment at "t"
 */
function splitNthPathSegmentAtT(pathData, i = 1, t = 0.5) {

  let pathData0 = [pathData[i - 1]];
  let pathData1 = [];
  let com = pathData[i];

  let [type, values] = [com.type, com.values];
  let valuesL = values.length;
  let comPrev = pathData[i - 1];
  let valuesPrev = comPrev ? comPrev.values : [];
  let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;
  let p0, cp1, cp2, p1, p2, m0, m1, m2, m3, m4;
  switch (type) {
    case "C":
      p0 = {
        x: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
        y: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
      };
      cp1 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 6],
        y: values[valuesL - 5]
      };
      cp2 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 4],
        y: values[valuesL - 3]
      };

      p1 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 2],
        y: values[valuesL - 1]
      };
      m0 = interpolatedPoint(p0, cp1, t);
      m1 = interpolatedPoint(cp1, cp2, t);
      m2 = interpolatedPoint(cp2, p1, t);
      m3 = interpolatedPoint(m0, m1, t);
      m4 = interpolatedPoint(m1, m2, t);

      // split end point
      p2 = interpolatedPoint(m3, m4, t);

      // first segment
      pathData0.push({
        type: "C",
        values: [m0.x, m0.y, m3.x, m3.y, p2.x, p2.y]
      });

      // second segment
      pathData1.push({
        type: "M",
        values: [p2.x, p2.y]
      });

      pathData1.push({
        type: "C",
        values: [m4.x, m4.y, m2.x, m2.y, p1.x, p1.y]
      });
      break;


    case "L":
      p0 = {
        x: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
        y: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
      };
      p1 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 2],
        y: values[valuesL - 1]
      };
      m1 = interpolatedPoint(p0, p1, t);
      // first segment
      pathData0.push({
        type: "L",
        values: [m1.x, m1.y]
      });
      // second segment
      pathData1.push({
        type: "M",
        values: [m1.x, m1.y]
      });
      pathData1.push({
        type: "L",
        values: [p1.x, p1.y]
      });
      break;

  }

  return [pathData0, pathData1];
}


/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
  //t: 0.5 - point in the middle
  if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
    p1.x = p1[0];
    p1.y = p1[1];
  }
  if (Array.isArray(p2)) {
    p2.x = p2[0];
    p2.y = p2[1];
  }
  let [x, y] = [(p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x, (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y];
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}
```

```css
.layout {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

svg{
width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.4/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path id="pathCubic" d="M0 100 C33.33 33.33 66.67 33.33 100 100" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
</svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path id="pathSplit0" d="" stroke="green" fill="none" />
<path id="pathSplit1" d="" stroke="red" fill="none" />
</svg>
</div>
```

I'm using `getPathData()` [polyfilled](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) to parse the `d` pathData attribute to an array of commands.

Helper function `splitNthPathSegmentAtT()` will calculate the new interpolated `C` command control points according to the desired `t` value.

#### Further reading

- See enxaneta's excellent post: [The Anatomy Of A Cubic Bézier Curve In SVG](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/how-to-add-a-point-to-an-svg-path)
- [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/mdjyeBe) including `Q` and `A` commands.

#### Split at pathLength

If you need to color you path at certain **lengths** you could use the `pathLength` attribute combined with `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`.
Not the same, since we're visually "splitting" (by duplicating the path and applying different stroke-dasharray values) according to a path length percentage.

```js
let t = 0.75;
let path = document.querySelector('#pathCubic');


/**
 * emulate split path by stroke-dasharray
 * split via path length
 */
path.setAttribute('pathLength', 1);
let clonedSeg = path.cloneNode();
let svg = path.closest('svg');
svg.appendChild(clonedSeg);


// 1. segment
path.setAttribute('stroke', 'green');
path.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', `0`);
path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${t} 1`);

// 2. segment
clonedSeg.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
clonedSeg.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', `-${t}`);
clonedSeg.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${1 - t} 1`);


/**
 * parse pathData
 * quadratic and arc commands will be converted to cubic
 */

let pathData = path.getPathData({
  normalize: true
});
let pathDataSplit = splitNthPathSegmentAtT(pathData, 1, t);

let d0 = pathDataSplit[0].map(com => {
  return `${com.type} ${com.values.join(' ')}`
}).join(' ');
let d1 = pathDataSplit[1].map(com => {
  return `${com.type} ${com.values.join(' ')}`
}).join(' ');

// apply path data
pathSplit0.setAttribute('d', d0);
pathSplit1.setAttribute('d', d1);



/**
 * split nth path segment at "t"
 */
function splitNthPathSegmentAtT(pathData, i = 1, t = 0.5) {

  let pathData0 = [pathData[i - 1]];
  let pathData1 = [];
  let com = pathData[i];

  let [type, values] = [com.type, com.values];
  let valuesL = values.length;
  let comPrev = pathData[i - 1];
  let valuesPrev = comPrev ? comPrev.values : [];
  let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;
  let p0, cp1, cp2, p1, p2, m0, m1, m2, m3, m4;
  switch (type) {
    case "C":
      p0 = {
        x: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
        y: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
      };
      cp1 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 6],
        y: values[valuesL - 5]
      };
      cp2 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 4],
        y: values[valuesL - 3]
      };

      p1 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 2],
        y: values[valuesL - 1]
      };
      m0 = interpolatedPoint(p0, cp1, t);
      m1 = interpolatedPoint(cp1, cp2, t);
      m2 = interpolatedPoint(cp2, p1, t);
      m3 = interpolatedPoint(m0, m1, t);
      m4 = interpolatedPoint(m1, m2, t);

      // split end point
      p2 = interpolatedPoint(m3, m4, t);

      // first segment
      pathData0.push({
        type: "C",
        values: [m0.x, m0.y, m3.x, m3.y, p2.x, p2.y]
      });

      // second segment
      pathData1.push({
        type: "M",
        values: [p2.x, p2.y]
      });

      pathData1.push({
        type: "C",
        values: [m4.x, m4.y, m2.x, m2.y, p1.x, p1.y]
      });
      break;


    case "L":
      p0 = {
        x: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
        y: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
      };
      p1 = {
        x: values[valuesL - 2],
        y: values[valuesL - 1]
      };
      m1 = interpolatedPoint(p0, p1, t);
      // first segment
      pathData0.push({
        type: "L",
        values: [m1.x, m1.y]
      });
      // second segment
      pathData1.push({
        type: "M",
        values: [m1.x, m1.y]
      });
      pathData1.push({
        type: "L",
        values: [p1.x, p1.y]
      });
      break;

  }


  return [pathData0, pathData1];
}


/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
  //t: 0.5 - point in the middle
  if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
    p1.x = p1[0];
    p1.y = p1[1];
  }
  if (Array.isArray(p2)) {
    p2.x = p2[0];
    p2.y = p2[1];
  }
  let [x, y] = [(p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x, (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y];
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}
```

```css
.layout {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

svg{
width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.4/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>


<div class="layout">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <path id="pathCubic" d="M0 100 C33.33 33.33 66.67 33.33 100 100" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
        </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <path id="pathSplit0" d="" stroke="green" fill="none" />
            <path id="pathSplit1" d="" stroke="red" fill="none" />
        </svg>
</div>
```

Left: split at pathLength*0.75; Right split at `t` 0.75.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. For others, if you don't see anything: div.layout needs a height (e.g. 100vh)

Comment: @Niklas: thanks for your feedback. Fixed the snippet (now running even in safari =)